# How to register users as admin only MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm working on a project and I have two separate apps and if I can combine them that would be great. One is a user app. However all the accounts have to be registered by admins not the users themselves. I created an admin app that lets them use office 365 to login and when I make a ado.net model of the client side app it shows password hash but I just need them to create standard passwords. I'm confused how to take the registration form and have it hash the passwords.

Comment: You can take the password that was entered in and use either MD5 or Sha1 to hash the passwords and save them to your database.

Comment: and I guess I could use the iPasswordHasher? What I would really like to do is take the registration part from the user authentication and move it to the enterprise authentication but I'm not sure you can use both for the same app.